# Codeigniter CSV upload then explode

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I have some code that uploads the CSV file to the specified folder, but it doesn't update the database.

```
public function do_upload()
{
    $csv_path = realpath(APPPATH . '/../assets/uploads/CSV/');
    $config['upload_path']   = $csv_path;
    $config['allowed_types'] = '*'; // All types of files allowed
    $config['overwrite']     = true; // Overwrites the existing file

    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->layout->buffer('content', 'program/upload', $error);
        $this->layout->render();
    }
    else
    {


        $image_data = $this->upload->data();
        $fname = $image_data['file_name'];
        $fpath = $image_data['file_path'].$fname;
        $fh = fopen($fpath, "r");



        $insert_str = 'INSERT INTO wc_program (JobRef, Area, Parish, AbbrWorkType, WorkType, Timing, TrafficManagement, Location, Duration, Start, Finish) VALUES '."\n";


        if ($fh) {

            // Create each set of values.
            while (($csv_row = fgetcsv($fh, 2000, ',')) !== false) {

                foreach ($csv_row as &$row) {
                    $row = strtr($row, array("'" => "\'", '"' => '\"'));
                }

                $insert_str .= '("'
                    // Implode the array and fix pesky apostrophes.
                    .implode('","', $csv_row)
                    .'"),'."\n";
            }

            // Remove the trailing comma.
            $insert_str = rtrim($insert_str, ",\n");

            // Insert all of the values at once.
            $this->db->set($insert_str);

            echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                        alert("Document successfully uploaded and saved to the database.");
                        location = "program/index";
                </script>';
        } 
        else {
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                        alert("Sorry! Something went wrong please proceed to try again.");
                        location = "program/upload";
                </script>';
        } 


    }
}
```

When I run var_dump($fh); it shows: resource(89) of type (stream)

When I run `var_dump($fpath)` it shows: `string(66) "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/site/assets/uploads/CSV/wc_program.csv"`

So it all uploads but what is wrong with it not updating the database?
I have tried all kinds of changing the `fopen` method but still no joy, I really need it to add to the database and the insert query and set query should do the trick but it doesn't.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have `db_debug` set to `TRUE` in `config/database.php`? It will display database errors. You can also try echoing `$this->db->last_query()` to see the last query it ran.

Answer (score 1):

You are not running any query on the database. You are mixing active record syntax with simple query syntax. The active record insert query will be executed by calling.

```
$this->db->insert('my_table');
```

`db::set()` does not actually query the database. It takes in a key/value pair that will be inserted or updated after `db::insert()` or `db::update()` is called. If you build the query yourself you need to use the `db::query()` function.

Review the [active directory documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html).

You can use `$this->db->query('put your query here')`, but you lose the benefit of CodeIgniter's built in security. Review [CodeIgniter's query](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html) functions.

I'll give you examples of just a few of the many ways you can insert into a database using CodeIgniter. The examples will generate the query from your comment. You will need to adjust your code accordingly.

**EXAMPLE 1**:

```
$result = $this->db
    ->set('JobRef', 911847)
    ->set('Area', 'Coastal')
    ->set('Parish', 'Yapton')
    ->set('AbbrWorkType', 'Micro')
    ->set('WorkType', 'Micro-Asphalt Surfacing')
    ->set('Timing', 'TBC')
    ->set('TrafficManagement', 'No Positive Traffic Management')
    ->set('Location', 'Canal Road (added PMI 16/07/12)')
    ->set('Duration', '2 days')
    ->set('Start', '0000-00-00')
    ->set('Finish', '0000-00-00') 
    ->insert('wc_program');

echo $this->db->last_query() . "\n\n";
echo "RESULT: \n\n";
print_r($result);
```

**EXAMPLE 2** (Using an associative array):

```
$row = array(
    'JobRef' => 911847,
    'Area' => 'Coastal',
    'Parish' => 'Yapton',
    'AbbrWorkType' => 'Micro',
    'WorkType' => 'Micro-Asphalt Surfacing',
    'Timing' => 'TBC',
    'TrafficManagement' => 'No Positive Traffic Management',
    'Location' => 'Canal Road (added PMI 16/07/12)',
    'Duration' => '2 days',
    'Start' => '0000-00-00',
    'Finish' => '0000-00-00'
);
$this->db->insert('wc_program', $row);
// This will do the same thing
// $this->db->set($row);
// $this->db->insert('wc_program');
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

Example 1 and 2 are using the Active Record. The information is stored piece by piece and then the query is built when you make the final call. This has several advantages. It allows you to build queries dynamically without worrying about SQL syntax and order of the keywords. It also escapes your data.

**EXAMPLE 3** (Simple Query):

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO 
    wc_program 
        (JobRef, Area, Parish, AbbrWorkType, WorkType, Timing, TrafficManagement, Location, Duration, Start, Finish) 
    VALUES 
        ("911847","Coastal","Yapton","Micro","Micro-Asphalt Surfacing","TBC","No Positive Traffic Management","Canal Road (added PMI 16/07/12)","2 days","0000-00-00","0000-00-00")';
$result = $this->db->query($query);
echo $this->db->last_query() . "\n\n";
echo "RESULT: \n";
print_r($result);
```

This way leaves all the protection against injection up to you, can lead to more errors, and is harder to change/maintain.

If you are going to do it this way you should use the following syntax, which will protect against injection.

**EXAMPLE 4**:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO 
    wc_program 
        (JobRef, Area, Parish, AbbrWorkType, WorkType, Timing, TrafficManagement, Location, Duration, Start, Finish) 
    VALUES 
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);';

$row = array(
    911847,
    'Coastal',
    'Yapton',
    'Micro',
    'Micro-Asphalt Surfacing',
    'TBC',
    'No Positive Traffic Management',
    'Canal Road (added PMI 16/07/12)',
    '2 days',
    '0000-00-00',
    '0000-00-00'
);

$result = $this->db->query($query, $row);
echo $this->db->last_query() . "\n\n";
echo "RESULT: \n";
print_r($result);
```

CodeIgniter will replace each "?" in the query with the corresponding value from the array after it is escaped. You can use this to run many queries that are of the same form, but have different data just by updating the `$row` array and benefit from CI's built in security.

Comment: $this->db->query() throws back and error saying i need to use set and $this->db->insert()also states You must use the "set" method to update an entry.

Comment: So to clarify it uploads the file but does not actually insert/update the database, it's like it's not reading the csv or the query isn't right.

Comment: Did a var_dump straight after the last query and i get this:    string(269504) "INSERT INTO wc_program (JobRef, Area, Parish, AbbrWorkType, WorkType, Timing, TrafficManagement, Location, Duration, Start, Finish) VALUES ("911847","Coastal","Yapton","Micro","Micro-Asphalt Surfacing","TBC","No Positive Traffic Management","Canal Road (added PMI 16/07/12)","2 days","0000-00-00","0000-00-00.... blah blah blah too big of file to post all of it, but the insert query is there

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for CodeIgniter's query function? You simply pass the query string to the function and it runs it. With the insert function you do need to use set(), but you don't pass it the full query. You actively build the query piece by piece.

Comment: But it comes from a csv file and there are over 1700 entries

Comment: You build the array inside your loop, just like you are currently building your query. This code is not a copy and paste solution, you will need to implement it in your own code.